# Why does Grails 2.4 add blobs to my database for contained domain objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We just upgraded from Grails 2.2.1 to Grails 2.4.2

After fixing everything, we noticed that some of our MySQL database tables have a few extra columns.

Here's the scenario:

```
class User {
    String username;
}

class Report {
    User issuedBy;
}
```

Before the upgrade, our MySQL table for Reports looked like this:

```
|id:int|version:int|issued_by_id:int|
```

After the upgrade, it looks like this:

```
|id:int|version:int|issued_by_id:int|issued_by:blob|
```

I can't figure out why this is, and don't want our production database to change once I deploy the new version.

Does anyone know what this extra field is, where it came from, and what it does?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that extra field should be there since that relationship is a simple ManyToOne which - by default - should be represented by the "issued_by_id" db field.

Try running "dbm-generate-changelog" afresh, to check if it creates the extra field. If so, it may be worth raising a ticket in the Grails JIRA.

Comment: It may be worth a JIRA, but you should never trust generated code, or in this case a generated changelog. It has a high likelihood of being correct, but you must verify that before applying the changes. The plugin doesn't promise bug-free easy migrations, only that it gets you most of the way there and hopefully minimizes the amount of human intervention.

Comment: I ran the change log, and it's highlighted even more unwanted changes. The upgrade has generated tables for derived classes, even though we're using table-per-hierarchy and the actual generated MySQL queries go through the proper shared table.

Comment: Both of the problems definitely seem like JIRA-worthy issues. Looks like I am staying on 2.3.9 for a little while longer :(

Comment: It's not 100%. The example I listed above is contrived and I haven't tested it. Every contained object in our domain class hierarchy hasn't generated extra blobs. I don't know what exact circumstances recreate this, which means creating a useful JIRA is difficult.